# Detection of colour in python

Tags: python, opencv

Does anyone know how I can make my program show when the camera detects certain colours? My program can currently detect colours (and shows a square box around detected colours), but I want the program to **show code when a specific colour is detected**.

Eg. Program to show 1 when it detects red, 0 when it detects green.

I'm not sure how to code the program to show that. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from firebase import firebase
import time
ha=1
new_users=[{"green":ha}]
 
db_url = 'https://autocar-3885c-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/'
fdb = firebase.FirebaseApplication(db_url, None)
fdb.post("/green",new_users)
red_lower = np.array([-10,100,100])
red_upper = np.array([10,255,255])#这里是设置颜色
#if red color ha=1
#if green color ha=0
#print(format(red_lower))
green_lower = np.array([35,43,46])
green_upper = np.array([77,255,255])
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 
cap.set(3, 320)
cap.set(4, 240)
 
while 1:
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (3, 3), 0)
   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)
   green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, green_lower, green_upper)
   mask = cv2.bitwise_or(red_mask, green_mask)
 
   # 图像学膨胀腐蚀
   mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
   mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3, 3), 0)
   res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
   # 寻找轮廓并绘制轮廓
   cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
 
   if len(cnts) > 0:
       # 寻找面积最大的轮廓并画出其最小外接圆
       cnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
       (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
       cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (255, 0, 255), 2)
       # 找到物体的位置坐标,获得颜色物体的位置，可以来控制小车的转向
       #print(int(x), int(y))
   else:
       pass
   cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
   cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
   cv2.imshow('res', res)
 
   if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
       break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you can put text on your image. using ```if-else``` statement you can write "green" or "red" depending on which value you have got

Comment: I can't understand so can you explain It more clearly, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the possible solutions:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


red_lower = np.array([-10, 100, 100])
red_upper = np.array([10, 255, 255])  # 这里是设置颜色
# if red color ha=1
# if green color ha=0
# print(format(red_lower))
green_lower = np.array([35, 43, 46])
green_upper = np.array([77, 255, 255])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(3, 320)
cap.set(4, 240)


def image_true_area(img):
    return np.count_nonzero(img)


out_number = -1
thresh = 200

while 1:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (3, 3), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)
    green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, green_lower, green_upper)

    out_number = np.argmax([image_true_area(green_mask), image_true_area(red_mask), thresh])
    out_number = out_number if out_number != 2 else -1

    mask = cv2.bitwise_or(red_mask, green_mask)

    # 图像学膨胀腐蚀
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3, 3), 0)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
    # 寻找轮廓并绘制轮廓
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # 寻找面积最大的轮廓并画出其最小外接圆
        cnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (255, 0, 255), 2)
        # 找到物体的位置坐标,获得颜色物体的位置，可以来控制小车的转向
        # print(int(x), int(y))
    else:
        pass

    cv2.putText(frame, str(out_number), (30, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('res', res)

    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the method called `image_true_area` that returns amount of *true* pixels on the given image. I have created a variable called `out_number` that will show **0** - if green, **1** - if red and **-1** - if nothing there (you can control threshold value changing `thresh`  variable). Then I just put `out_number` variable as text into `frame` mat.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answering. I have a followup question, is it possible to only show the variables (0, 1, -1) in python and not show them on the images themselves? Thanks in advance!

Comment: of course, just replace ```cv2.putText(frame, str(out_number), (30, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)``` with ```print(out_number)```

Comment: Or you can see the red and green values ​​on the display

Comment: Dude, please learn about ```python``` and ```opencv``` basics. If YOU wrote this code, then you can simply do it. At this forum no one will teach you.

Comment: I have succeeded

Comment: I would like to ask about the syntax of this line out_number = out_number if out_number != 2 else -1